# How to get applied validator class, if you we have UIComponent?

Tags: jsf

In my JSF page I have to apply Field Level Protection. In my code I am getting UIComponent by iterating over UIViewRoot. Is there any way to get applied validator class on that UIComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer for this question. As if your component is of type `UIInput` you can get the validators applied on that by calling method `getValidator()` which is available in `UIInput` class of `javax.faces.component` package.